# Python websocket client and multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, multiprocessing

I try to create a websocket client that spawns a new process with running websocket. Connection works great, I receive messages from connection, but when I call websocket.close() client keeps running and I have to terminate process in order to stop it. Here is a code sample:

```
import websocket
from multiprocessing import Process
from ...utils import wait

class Client:
  def __init__():
    self.baseUrl = "wss://<url>"
    self.ws = None
    self.ws_process = None
  
  def _on_open(self, ws):
    ws.send("<Subscription message>")
  
  def _on_close(self, ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print(f'Close status code: {close_status_code}. Msg: {close_msg}')

  def _on_message(self, ws, message):
    print(message)

  def open_connection(self):
    self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
        self.baseUrl,
        on_close=self._on_close,
        on_open=self._on_open,
        on_message=self._on_message
    )
    self.ws_process = Process(target=self.ws.run_forever)
    self.ws_process.start()
    return self.ws

  def stop_websocket_app(self):
    self.ws.close()
    # Wait until process is not alive
    process_is_not_alive = wait(lambda: not self.ws_process.is_alive(), 10)
    
    if process_is_not_alive:
        print("Websocket process is not alive, closing process gracefully..")
        self.ws_process.close()
    else:
        print('Websocket process did not stop running in 10 seconds, terminating it...')
        # process did not stop running in 10 sec period, terminate it
        self.ws_process.terminate()
        
    self.ws_process = None

client = Client()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  client.open_connection()
  client.stop_websocket_app()
```

Code above prints `'Websocket process did not stop running in 10 seconds, terminating it...'` to the terminal. Is there a way to stop websocket from running so I would be able to `close` process gracefully?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the `wait` function. 
Also `self.ws_process` is brutal.

Comment: Sidenote: Do you have a hard requirement to use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I spent around half an hour trying to figure out how to display it nicely, didn't work.

Comment: @HariharanRagothaman Here is wait function:   
```def wait(func: Callable, timeout: int = 5, interval: int = 1, *args, **kwargs) -> bool:
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < timeout:
        if func(*args):
            return True
        time.sleep(interval)
    return False```

Comment: @HariharanRagothaman I don't have a hard requirement to use multiprocessing. But I need to start multiple websockets simultaneously + have a main process that runs code based on the info that is coming from those websockets.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my queries. Going to modify your code / implementation and add an answer.